# Como puedo limitar el espacio donde aparece el texto en un moodle programado con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, moodle

Estoy haciendo un moodle interactivo para alumnos y he creado con javascript y html una plantilla que me facilite escribir formulas matemáticas y demás en lenguaje html con facilidad.

Mi problema aparece cuando quiero insertar el enunciado de un problema en el moodle. Éste, en vez de cambiar de linea cuando sobrepasa el espacio de la pantalla, sigue escribiendose en la misma linea, haciendo que aparezca una barra para ver más allá.

Hay alguna posibilidad para que pueda delimitar el texto a un espacio (impuesto por pixeles por ejemplo) a través de javascript?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Se requiere que muestres el codigo que estas usando

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer directamente con HTML, añadiendo `maxlength` al input donde estás escribiendo, de esta manera, limitas el número de carácteres que pueda insertar:

```
<input type="text" id="username" maxlength="10">
```

En caso de que lo quieras hacer con JavaScript, podrías utilizar algo parecido a esto:

```
document.getElementById("username").setAttribute('maxlength', '10');
```

Lo que haces es lo mismo que harías directamente en el HTML pero, se lo pasas con el método `setAttribute`